# Value being added to an array twice and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Using checkboxes I'm trying to add the value of the checkbox to the array when clicked. It seems to be adding fine but twice.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id= "checkboxes">
<label> Types of Places</label>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="woodland" class="places"/>
    <label for="woodland"><img src="../img/Woodland.jpg" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="lodging" class="places"/>
    <label for="viewpoint"><img src="../img/Viewpoint.jpg" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="restaurant" class="places"/>
    <label for="restaurant"><img src="../img/Restaurant.jpg" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="museum" class="places" />
    <label for="historical"><img src="../img/Historical.jpg" /></label>
  </form>
```

and here's the relevant JS/JQuery:

```
var placeT = [];

function initialize() {
    // Default the map view to UK
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.3781, -3.4360),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 5
    };

    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);

    $(".places").change(function() {
        $(".places").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                placeT.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert(placeT);
    });

}

function findPlaces(boxes, searchIndex) {



    var request = {
        bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
        types: [placeT]
    };

    // alert(request.bounds);
    service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            alert("Request[" + searchIndex + "] failed: " + status);

        }
        // alert(results.length);
        document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds[" + searchIndex + "] returns " + results.length + " results<br>"
        for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
            var marker = createMarker(result);
        }
        searchIndex++;
        if (searchIndex < boxes.length)
            findPlaces(boxes, searchIndex);
    });
}
```

I know it's probably something simple but I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You never empty the `placeT` array ?

Comment: It adds 2 instances from one click of the checkbox, would emptying the array fix this?

Comment: Then most likely `initialize` runs twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as below :

```
 $(".places").change(function()
    {
        placeT = [];
        $(".places").each(function()
        {
            if( $(this).is(':checked') )
            {
                placeT.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert( placeT );
    });
```

Comment: I was going to accept the answer as soon as the timer ran out, there's 5 minutes left.